# I cannot launch terminal in vscode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to launch my terminal in vscode but the error below keeps popping. I have check to make sure that my internal integrated configurations is correct  but it still not working.
n

The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Error launching WinPTY agent: winpty-agent CreateProcess failed: cmdline='"\?\C:\Users\Kenechukwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\node-pty\build\Release\winpty-agent.exe" \.\pipe\winpty-control-7208-1-1d66132ca95c7eb-524fd0804596bb972af689bcf7fb5c3a 0 1 80 24' err=0xc1).

Comment: Sometimes more useful error messages can surface if you go into Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is similar to [microsoft/vscode issue 80855](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80855):

> I think this is just how the errors where something blocks `winpty` from creating the process show themselves now.
> You need to get your admins to whitelist
>
> ```
> c:\Apps\vscode\resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\node-pty\build\Release\winpty-agent.exe
> ```
>
> Some anti-virus software blocks winpty agent from running which is what creates the terminal process, your options are to get admin to allow it or update to Windows 10 1903 where we've moved off that system and onto one provided by the MS console team.

The [OP luca76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3675575/luca76) points out to another factor [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062985/i-cannot-launch-terminal-in-vscode/63067900?noredirect=1#comment113160329_63067900):

> I had a **Group Policy** from my **domain Active Directory** that was blocking this executable.

Comment: Not really, I have removed disabled all my antivirus. Though I can use the terminal now but this time I opened it through vscode... Thanks though.

Comment: I had a Group Policy  from my domain Active Directory that was blocking this executable. Thank you!

Comment: @luca76 Good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.